# swift type constraints on generic extensions

Tags: generics, swift, swift-extensions

After some amount of stress, I created the following generic function:

```
func removeDupes<T : Hashable > (inout inputCollection : [T] ) -> [T] {
  var hashMap = [T : Bool]()
  var output = 0
  for thing in inputCollection {
    if !hashMap[thing] {
      hashMap[thing] = true
      inputCollection[output++] = thing
    }
  }
  while (inputCollection.count > output) {
    inputCollection.removeLast()
  }
  return inputCollection
}
```

So when you do:

```
var names = ["Bob", "Carol", "Bob", "Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Ted", "Alice", "Ted", "Alice"]
removeDupes(&names)
```

names will contain: ["Bob", "Carol","Ted", "Alice"]

Now I'd like to generically add "removeDupes" as an extension method on Array and I'm floundering with the syntax, since I have to constrain it to be an array of Hashable items.

I was hoping I could declare it like this:

```
extension Array {
  func removeDupes< T : Hashable> () -> [T] {
    return removeDupes(&self)
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

Array is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T5'

I suspect the answer is either "you idiot, do this..." or "you can't do it"

Which will it be? :-D

Answer (score 3):

`Array` class is declared like this:

```
public struct Array<Element>
```

Since Swift 2.0 you **can** create extension methods only for instances where the generic `Element` parameter conforms to a protocol:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    @warn_unused_result
    func removeDupes() -> [Element] {
        var hashMap = [Element : Bool]()
        var result = [Element]()

        for thing in self {
            if hashMap[thing] == nil {
                hashMap[thing] = true
                result.append(thing)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Notice the `where` statement in the extension declaration. This way, the `removeDupes` method is only declared for arrays of `Hashable` elements:

```
let names = ["Bob", "Carol", "Bob", "Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Ted", "Alice", "Ted", "Alice"]
let uniqueNames = names.removeDupes()   // returns ["Bob", "Carol", "Ted", "Alice"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a templated method for a generic that is more restrictive than the generic itself (only works with some forms of the generic).

Also, when you are defining T in your extension method, you are defining a new T unrelated to the T defined in the Array. There is no need to redefine T and ultimately that is the problem you are running into. It is fine do define new templates within a generic, but there is no way to relate those templates to both T and a protocol.

Your original function is the best way to implement that, although it would potentially be better to return a copy of the array without the duplicates instead of modifying the original. This makes the code more clear and is better for multithreading (which may be important for a method that does this much processing).

Answer (score 2):

Array is defined as `Array<T>`, which means that an Array can hold any type T, and T does not necessarily conform to the `Hashable` protocol.  Therefore, you cannot apply methods that require this constraint. Unfortunately, you can also not check against or downcast to this protocol, because `Hashable` [was not declared with the `@objc` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_403).

It is possible to remove duplicates by using a Dictionary, but you cannot use T for keys, for the same reason mentioned above. However, if T is uniquely representable as a String, this should work:

```
extension Array {
    func unique()->Array<T> {
        var buffer = Dictionary<String,T>()
        for it in self {
            buffer["\(it)"] = it
        }
        return Array(buffer.values)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, although as drewag suggests, this one returns a copy. The global function takes any `SequenceType`, but always returns an `Array` because `SequenceType` is a very general type that does not allow appending values.

```
public func unique<H: Hashable, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == H>(sequence: S) -> [H] {
    var hashMap = [H: Bool]()
    var result = [H]()
    for elem in sequence {
        let key = hashMap[elem]
        if key == nil {
            hashMap[elem] = true
            result.append(elem)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Then, in your `Array` extension:

```
public func unique<H: Hashable>() -> [H] {
    return Yeah.unique(map({ $0 as H }))
}
```

I'm not crazy about this solution because the array is traversed twice: once to map it to Hashable, and then again to iterate it to remove the duplicates. The advantage of it is that by delegating to a global function, you can very quickly add a `unique` method to any class that adopts `SequenceType`. I also don't like the fact that you are forced to return an `Array`. The way to solve that is probably to have an overload of the global `unique` with a closure that knows how to append a value. Food for thought.

Comment: I've created a [gist for this](https://gist.github.com/Revolucent/c45583823e8604ca3eaa) if anyone's interested.